# Hostname of rabbitmq connections

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to see the hostname of a connected unit in RabbitMQ server (management plugin view) instead of just the IP/port? We use dynamic connection locations and it would be easier to identify clients that way...

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there are no such built-in feature.

As an alternative way, you can use [Management Plugin CLI interface](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html) or [Management Plugin HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_4/priv/www/api/index.html) (make sure you are browsing appropriate version) to get connections IP and then manually resolve them.

If it's an option for you, you can user per-host or per-hosts-group users each with the same permissions.

Comment: I ended up sending hostnames using the product client property, that's good enough for me now. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Nice catch! If client library allows to do such trick it's probably the easiest way.

Comment: @pinepain what is the easiest way of identifying what the hostname for RabbitMQ is? I have an app and, locally I just use `localhost` and that works, but when deployed, I used the node name e.g. `rabbit@578149-DVA04` and that gives me a connection refusal error.

Comment: I don't fully get what do you mean? What problem are you solving? By default nodename has format rabbit@$HOSTNAME (see https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) so from default nodename you can get hostname, if I get you right.